# How to prove that the cardinality of an aleatory set is a Markov Chain.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I'm having trouble solving this exercices:
Let $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,...$ i.i.d with uniform distribution in {$1,2,...,N$} and let $X_n=|\{\zeta_1,...,\zeta_n\}|$, show that $X_n$ is a Markov chain and compute its transition matrix.

I managed to write the transition matrix but i can't show that $$ P[X_n=i_n|X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},...,X_1=i_1]=P[X_n=i_n|X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}].$$
I have tried to write recursively $X_n$ in terms of $X_{n-1}$ but i failed.

Comment: **Hint:** $X_n=i_{n-1},\ $ if $\xi_n\in\{\xi_1,\dots,\xi_{n-1}\}. \qquad$   
$X_n=i_{n-1}+1,\ $ if $\xi_n\notin\{\xi_1,\dots,\xi_{n-1}\}$

Comment: I have noticed that but how i translate it in terms of probability?